# Vue 3 Understanding examples from setup function and applying them in Setup tag

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework, vue-component, vuejs3

I am new to vue but scince i am fresh starting i decied to go straight up to TS and Setup tag because seems like the newest and best way to write vue js components.

Anyways i am now looking at this [framework](https://ionicframework.com/) and more specific i'm into this example:

```
import { IonPage, onIonViewWillEnter, onIonViewDidEnter, onIonViewWillLeave, onIonViewDidLeave } from '@ionic/vue';
import { defineComponent } from 'vue';

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'Home',
  components: {
    IonPage,
  },
  setup() {
    onIonViewDidEnter(() => {
      console.log('Home page did enter');
    });
    ... the other hooks ...        
  },
});
```

And my question come from this block:

```
  name: 'Home',
  components: {
    IonPage,
  },
```

since i only worked with options api and setup tag i an not sure **What does it imply to put an object in the components object** and how could i acomplish the same objective with setup tag.

My objective is to make sure i am doing what this Note in the guide warns me about:

> Note Pages in your app need to be using the IonPage component in order
> for lifecycle methods and hooks to fire properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `<script setup>` syntax, **Home.vue** would look like this:

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
import { IonPage, onIonViewDidEnter, ...other hooks used here... } from '@ionic/vue';
onIonViewDidEnter(() => {
  console.log('Home page did enter');
});
...other hooks used here...
</script>
```

The note you quoted draws attention to the template of any page/view contents needing to be wrapped in a `<ion-page></ion-page>` wrapper for the layout to function as intended, like in their examples.

Generic example:

```html
<template>
  <ion-page>
    <ion-header>
      <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-title>Some title</ion-title>
      </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-header>
    <ion-content>
      some content...
    </ion-content>
  </ion-page>
</template>
```

For the above layout, you'd need to import all used components:

```js
import { IonPage, IonHeader, IonToolbar, IonTitle, IonContent } from '@ionic/vue'
```

With `<script setup>` you don't need to declare them as local components, `<script setup>` detects them and does it for you, behind the scenes. They're available for usage inside the `<template>` once imported.

The component `name` is also inferred by `<script setup>` from the name of the file. In the above case, it would be `Home`.

---

To sum up: behind the scenes, `<script setup>` takes its contents and wraps it in a

```js
export default defineComponent({
  name: // infer from file name,
  components: { 
    // list all imported vue components
  },
  setup() {

    // actual contents of `<script setup>`

  }
})
```

For this to be possible, some helpers were added (`defineEmits`, `defineProps`), which allow declaring those parts of Options API inside the `setup()` function.

Most notably, in this syntax `setup()` no longer needs a `return` value. All variables declared or imported inside it are made available to `<template>`.

---

Important: `<script setup>` is a useful tool, designed to reduce boilerplate in the majority of cases, not to replace `defineComponent()` completely. Read more about it [in the docs](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#usage-alongside-normal-script).